# XElement default namespace on attributes provides unexpected behaviour

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml, xml-namespaces, xelement

I am having trouble creating an XML document that contains a default namespace and a named namespace, hard to explain easier to just show what I am trying to produce...

```
<Root xmlns="http://www.adventure-works.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:SchemaLocation="http://www.SomeLocatation.Com/MySchemaDoc.xsd">
  <Book title="Enders Game" author="Orson Scott Card" />
  <Book title="I Robot" author="Isaac Asimov" />
</Root>
```

but what I end up with is this...

```
<Root xmlns="http://www.adventure-works.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:SchemaLocation="http://www.SomeLocatation.Com/MySchemaDoc.xsd">
  <Book p3:title="Enders Game" p3:author="Orson Scott Card" xmlns:p3="http://www.adventure-works.com" />
  <Book p3:title="I Robot" p3:author="Isaac Asimov" xmlns:p3="http://www.adventure-works.com" />
</Root>
```

The code that I wrote to produce this XML snippet is this...

```
  XNamespace aw = "http://www.adventure-works.com";
  XNamespace xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
  XElement root = new XElement(aw + "Root",
      new XAttribute("xmlns", "http://www.adventure-works.com"),
      new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"),
      new XAttribute(xsi + "SchemaLocation", "http://www.SomeLocatation.Com/MySchemaDoc.xsd"),

      new XElement(aw + "Book",
        new XAttribute(aw + "title", "Enders Game"),
        new XAttribute(aw + "author", "Orson Scott Card")),
      new XElement(aw + "Book",
        new XAttribute(aw + "title", "I Robot"),
        new XAttribute(aw + "author", "Isaac Asimov")));
```

based on an [example on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387075.aspx)

****EDIT****

Ok, with some more experimentation I am now very confused on how XML namespaces work....

if I remove the aw + theattribute I get what I was after...but now it seems that what I was after is not actually what I expected. I thought that namespaces were inherited from their parents, is this not true of attributes as well? because, this code to read the attributes does not work as I expected...

```
  XElement xe = XElement.Parse(textBox1.Text);
  XNamespace aw = "http://www.adventure-works.com";
  var qry = from x in xe.Descendants(aw + "Book")
            select (string)x.Attribute(aw + "author");
```

However if I remove the aw + on the attribute its ok, leading me to assume that I cannot have attributes in the default namespace. Is this correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Good question. I dug around a bit, and found [this bit of the XML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#defaulting):

> A default namespace declaration
>   applies to all unprefixed element
>   names within its scope. Default
>   namespace declarations do not apply
>   directly to attribute names; the
>   interpretation of unprefixed
>   attributes is determined by the
>   element on which they appear.

It later goes on to give this example:

> For example, each of the bad empty-element tags is illegal in the following:

```
<!-- http://www.w3.org is bound to n1 and n2 -->
<x xmlns:n1="http://www.w3.org" 
   xmlns:n2="http://www.w3.org" >
  <bad a="1"     a="2" />
  <bad n1:a="1"  n2:a="2" />
</x>
```

> However, each of the following is legal, the second because the default namespace does not > apply to attribute names:

```
<!-- http://www.w3.org is bound to n1 and is the default -->
<x xmlns:n1="http://www.w3.org" 
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org" >
  <good a="1"     b="2" />
  <good a="1"     n1:a="2" />
</x>
```

So basically, it looks like attribute names don't get namespaces by default, which explains everything you've seen :)

Comment: very interesting indeed. XML namespace are not fun ;-)

Comment: Agreed, although LINQ to XML makes them nicer to work with than any other framework I've seen.

Answer (score 1):

```cs
XElement doc = XElement.Parse(ToXml());
doc.DescendantsAndSelf().Attributes().Where(a => a.IsNamespaceDeclaration).Remove();
var ele = doc.DescendantsAndSelf();
foreach (var el in ele)
    el.Name = ns != null ? ns + el.Name.LocalName : el.Name.LocalName;
```

For anyone else who spent 2 days trying to find an answer.