# Add xml namespace to XDocument

Tags: c#, xml

the output the i need is

```
<ns1:collection>
<ns1:child1>value1</ns1:child3>
    <ns1:child2>value2</ns1:child3>
    <ns1:child3>value3</ns1:child3>
</ns1:collection>
```

i try to do it by the code below - but i get an exception -...

How to add the namespace on this one ??

```
XDocument xDoc = new XDocument( new XElement( "collection",
                 new XElement( "ns1:child1", value1 ),
                 new XElement( "ns1:child2", value2 ),
                 new XElement( "ns1:child3", value3 ) ) );
```

I also try to use the

```
          XNamespace ns1 = "http://url/for/ns1";";
```

and to do

```
           ( ns1 + "child1", value1 )
```

And still nothing

Comment: what is the output/error you are getting after using ( ns1 + "child1", value1 )?

Comment: in there there isno exception - just wrong xml out

Comment: this may help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1338517/how-can-i-write-xml-with-a-namespace-and-prefix-with-xelement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move namespace declaration to the fictional parent element:

```
XDocument xDoc = new XDocument(new XElement("root",
            new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "ns1", ns1),
                new XElement(ns1 + "collection",
                    new XElement(ns1 + "child1", value1),
                    new XElement(ns1 + "child2", value2),
                     new XElement(ns1 + "child3", value3))));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        XDocument xDoc = new XDocument(new XElement(ns1+"collection",
            new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns+"ns1",ns1),
             new XElement(ns1+ "child1", value1),
             new XElement(ns1+"child2", value2),
             new XElement(ns1+"child3", value3)));
```

Comment: But on this i will have the collection with the namespace - and i need the "collection" in as clear case => this is not good :(