# How to make a xml document and sending it to an ftp from winform or .net site

Tags: c#, .net, xml, winforms

Hello programmers of stackoverflow.

I need your help. I need to make a system that can make an xml file and then send it to a companys server so that the xml file gets registred and can create a new object in their database. But the xml file needs to be in a speciffic format and have some speciffic namespaces. I have a document from the company on how it could look like and with all the namespaces that is needed in the document. The problem is i dont know how to get all of the namespaces and the other important information from this xml document and get that in to a new system that i have to make. I basically have no idear on how to get started on this project. hope some of you can help.

I can post the xml document that i have from the company if it is needed. Sorry for the bad english gramma.

Comment: Isn't it the same as in this Stackoverflow article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1338517/how-can-i-write-xml-with-a-namespace-and-prefix-with-xelement?

Comment: Hello Klaudiusz bryjamus, yes that is how you use more that one namespace thank you for that! but i still ned help with how to figure out how to get all the infomation that i need. Dont know how to explain it properly i think.

Comment: this question is pretty broad in scope... you said you have no idea how to get started, but it sounds like you've got a pretty good idea of what needs to happen. Try google for 'C# XML' and 'WCF web service' and you should find plenty of reading material to get you started.

Comment: Hey DrewJordan. Yes you are right it is a pretty broad scope! i am just really new to working with xml like this. Guess i will try reading a little more about it and see if i can figure out a good solution.