# Shouldn't an XElement inherit the namespace from its parent Xelement?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, namespaces

I'm using Linq for XML in .NET 3.5 for the first time, and I'm having some trouble with namespaces. Namely, the XElement is printed like this : `<opf:metadata>` when I just want it to say `<metadata>`.

Here is the code:

```
    XNamespace opfNamespace = "http://www.idpf.org/2007/opf";
        XNamespace xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
        XNamespace dcterms = "http://purl.org/dc/terms/";
        XNamespace dc = "http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/";

        opfRoot = new XElement(opfNamespace + "package",
                                    new XAttribute("version", "2.0"),
                                    new XAttribute("unique-identifier", "uuid_id"));
        XElement metadata = new XElement(opfNamespace + "metadata",
                                    new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi", xsi),
                                    new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "opf", opfNamespace),
                                    new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "dcterms", dcterms),
                                    new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "dc", dc),
                                    new XElement(dc + "language", "pt-BR"));
        opfRoot.Add(metadata);
```

And here is the result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package version="2.0" unique-identifier="uuid_id" xmlns="http://www.idpf.org/2007/opf">
  <opf:metadata xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:opf="http://www.idpf.org/2007/opf" xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
    <dc:language>pt-BR</dc:language>
  </opf:metadata>
</package>
```

I expected it the metadata element to come without the opf: "opf:metadata"

If I remove the opfNameSpace  from {opfNameSpace + "metadata"}, I get a blank xmlns namespace (xmlns="") in the metadata element.

I looked at this thread:

[How can I write xml with a namespace and prefix with XElement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1338517/how-can-i-write-xml-with-a-namespace-and-prefix-with-xelement)

and this one:

[XElement default namespace on attributes provides unexpected behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231396/xelement-default-namespace-on-attributes-provides-unexpected-behaviour)

But they didn't solve my problem. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you're redeclaring the opf namespace alias in the metadata element. Just remove this attribute:

```
new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "opf", opfNamespace)
```

from the `<metadata>` constructor call, and it works fine:

```
<package version="2.0" unique-identifier="uuid_id"
         xmlns="http://www.idpf.org/2007/opf">
  <metadata xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:dcterms=
"http://purl.org/dc/terms/" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
    <dc:language>pt-BR</dc:language>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

Now you could argue that because you're redeclaring the namespace alias to have the same URL as before, it should be irrelevant - to be honest, I don't know what the spec says about that. But it seems somewhat reasonable.

On the other hand, I believe the two XML forms should end up being treated equivalently by anything parsing them, so if it's more convenient to create the `metadata` element with all the relevant declarations, then it shouldn't cause any problems... AFAIK :)

Comment: Ok, that works. I wanted to keep the ´xmlns:opf="http://www.idpf.org/2007/opf"´ in the metadata tag, but I suppose its redundant.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "opf", opfNamespace),`.

Comment: How do you figure it was answered first? Both showed the same timestamp. And I marked the other because it was more complete.

Answer (score 0):

Since the namespace formatting I needed was very specific, and it wasnt't being generated correctly even with the opf:metadata problem resolved, I found a better way. I just created a XmlDocument mannualy, and added the XML. From there I can edit it programatically. Like so:

```
            XmlDocumentopf = new XmlDocument();
            opf.LoadXml("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ?>" +
                            "<package version=\"2.0\" unique-identifier=\"uuid_id\" xmlns=\"http://www.idpf.org/2007/opf\">" +
                            "<metadata xmlns:dc=\"http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/\" xmlns:opf=\"http://www.idpf.org/2007/opf\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:dcterms=\"http://purl.org/dc/terms/\">" +
                            "<dc:title>Title of this book</dc:title>" +
                            "<dc:language>pt-BR</dc:language>" +
                            "<dc:identifier id=\"uuid_id\" opf:scheme=\"uuid\">a335de4c-560f-4b75-bcba-1418b726f92c</dc:identifier>" +
                            "<dc:creator opf:role=\"aut\">Desconhecido(a)</dc:creator>" +
                            "<dc:date>2011-01-31T11:59:46.949000+00:00</dc:date>" +
                            "<meta name=\"cover\" content=\"book-cover\"/>" +
                            "</metadata>" +
                            "<manifest />" +
                            "<spine toc=\"ncx\" />" +
                            "<guide />" +
                            "</package>");
```